# How can I use wokkel xmpp with a SOCKS proxy (e.g. txsocksx)?

Tags: python, xmpp, twisted, socks, wokkel

I've had some success writing an XMPP client using the wonderful `wokkel.xmppim` module.  I would like to send my XMPP traffic through a SOCKS proxy (v4a or v5).

I've had some success getting `txsocksx` to work with `twisted.web.client.Agent` by overriding `t.w.c.Agent._getEndpoint`.

Can something functionally equivalent be achieved in wokkel, perhaps using `wokkel.xmppim.MessageProtocol`
?

Comment: `_getEndpoint` is a private API.  It may be changed or removed at any point without warning.  You can tell because of the leading `_`.  If you need this API to be public, please consider contributing such a change to Twisted so that it will be maintained going forward :).

Comment: @Glyph, Duly noted!  Do you mean that you would be interested in a pull-request from my SOCKSAgent class?